# Honorable graphic designers and their greatest designs

Tags: designers

The rules is simple. **One name** in answer, up to **three links** to design examples.

You can put one image in the answer. This image should be in **public domain** and must not exceed **335 pixels** in any dimension.

Comment: Given that graphic design is very much commercial art, finding public domain images of work seems illogical. Either way, this sounds like homework help more than a GD question.

Comment: Define a "dishonorable" graphic designer.

Comment: @DA01 - I'd like to know more about _history_ of GD. Do you mean there should be timespan for this question?

Comment: I think this site would benefit greatly from GD history and theory questions. I was commenting more on your specific requirements for answers. Seems like some professor's home work assignment. ;)

Comment: I agree the restrictions make it read a great deal like a homework assignment. Why not.... "who are some influential designers in history? Please post samples and links." Without all the chains, man. :)

Comment: I added this rules because of no need for long answers in the question. We can't get right answer here, just many different views.

Comment: As much as I love wiki-style questions, it's been discussed and agreed that they are not a good fit for a Q&A site.

Comment: I think this question could bring some interesting answers, but unfortunately it's way outside the site's current criteria for acceptable questions.  Please participate in [the meta](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/386/lets-chat-about-graphic-design-se-updated-sept-6) if you think this is the type of question that could help this site.

Comment: @Scott Eric Gill had some extremely (criminally) dishonourable moments...

Answer (score 2):

Gerd Arnzt (1900-1988) is the great sign maker. His sings are drawn with preciseness and a wonderful feeling for dimensions.

http://www.gerdarntz.org/

[image]